# How do I compare vector and matrix columns that satisfy a condition?

Tags: matlab, vector, compare

I have a `12x3` matrix:

```
point1 = [7.5   4   5
          8.5   4   5
         9.5    4   5
         10.5   4   5
         11.5   4   5
         7      4   5.5
         12     4   5.5
         6.5    4   6
        12.5    4   6
           6    4   6.5
          13    4   6.5
         5.5    4   7];
```

The following two vectors were obtained from `point1` after certain procedure.

```
A1 = [7.5,4,5]; 
A8 = [6.5,4,6];
```

the row indices of `A1 and A8` respectively in `point1` are `AIdx == 1` and `AIdx == 8`.

What I would want is to compare both of `A1 and A8` to see which of them (or possibly both) has a non-integer at the same column as the **6th row of point1**.

I have tried the following code:

```
AIdx = find(ismember(point1, vertcat(A1, A8), 'rows'));

    for ii = 1: numel(AIdx)

    % In case where a close point is found, compare if they are both in the same plane
    if isequal( mod(point1(AIdx(ii),:),1)~=0, mod(point1(6,:),1)~=0 )== true    
        point1(AIdx(ii),:) = [NaN,NaN,NaN];  %invalidate all AIdx in the same plane as point1

    elseif isequal( mod(point1(AIdx(ii),:),1)~=0, mod(point1(6,:),1)~=0 )== false   
        AIdx(ii,:) = [];
    end
end
```

However, I get the error message: **“Index exceeds matrix dimensions.”** and I have a feeling this is coming from the part

```
mod(Point1(AIdx(ii),:),1)
```

whereby at `ii = 2 (hence AIdx=8)` there comes a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First about your error message:

In the first iteration you delete `AIdx(1,:)` in the elseif part. Therefore `AIdx` has afterwards only one element left, leading `AIdx(2)`to throw said error. What was the purpose of that part in the first place?

Now about your comparison:

It is only true if ALL non integers are at the same place. Unless I have greatly misunderstood the question, you wanted to check if even ONE non integer is at the same place.

```
for ii = 1: numel(AIdx)
    if any((mod(point1(AIdx(ii),:),1)~=0) & (mod(point1(6,:),1)~=0)) % check if ANY non integer is at the same place
        point1(AIdx(ii),:) = NaN;
    end
end
```

Also, here is a version without loop:

```
nonIntSix = repmat((mod(point1(6,:),1)~=0),2,1); % get indices of non integers in row six
NonIntA = mod(point1(AIdx,:),1)~=0; % same for A1 and A8
point1(AIdx(max(nonIntSix&NonIntA,[],2)),:) = NaN; % NaN all rows where at least one element the same
```

Or as single liner (faster):

```
point1(AIdx(max((mod(point1(AIdx,:),1)~=0) & (repmat((mod(point1(6,:),1)~=0),2,1)),[],2)),:) = NaN;
```

Comment: It works now. I see i didn't need to delete `Aidx` after the `"elseif"`.  Thank you so much!